# What is the correct way to dispose of SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle when AcquirePointer is used?

Tags: c#, dispose, memory-mapped-files, unsafe

I have some code which opens a memory mapped file and exposes a `ReadOnlySlice<T>` for a number of parsing operations. Simplified class code below:

```
public MemoryMappedViewAccessor Accessor { get; }
public SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle Handle { get; }
public byte* Memory;
private long _size;

public Parser(MemoryMappedFile mappedFile, long offset, long size)
{
    _size = size;
    Accessor = mappedFile.CreateViewAccessor(offset, _size, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read);
    Handle = Accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle;
    unsafe
    {
        Handle.AcquirePointer(ref Memory);
    }
}

public ReadOnlySlice<T> GetSpan<T>(int offset, int size)
{
    return new ReadOnlySpan<T>(chunk.Memory, _size).Slice(offset, size);
}

/* other functions exposing various Slice<T> over this */
```

Obviously this requires my class to implement `IDisposable`, but I am unsure as to where the boundary lies between unsafe and safe resources. One [reference I found](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2011/06/06/memory-mapped-file-quirks-greg/) says that `SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle` is a managed resource and should be disposed as such, but it doesn't mention how this changes with `ReleasePointer`, or whether `ReleasePointer` should even be called before `Dispose`.

The way I see it, the following two `Dispose` patterns are my options:

**Option 1 - Treat everything as managed**

```
private bool _isDisposed = false;

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_isDisposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Accessor.Dispose();
            Handle.ReleasePointer(); // is this even needed?
            Handle.Dispose();
        }

        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
}
```

**Option 2 - Treat pointer release as unmanaged**

```
private bool _isDisposed = false;

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_isDisposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Accessor.Dispose();
        }

        Handle.ReleasePointer();
        Handle.Dispose();

        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}

~FileChunk()
{
    Dispose(false);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

In both of these cases I would add a check to my parsing logic to throw an `ObjectDisposedException` if `_isDisposed` is true, to avoid UAF bugs and memory corruption.

Which of these is the correct dispose pattern when unsafe pointers are exposed from a `SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle`? Additionally, is it worth setting the `Memory` field to null during disposal?

Comment: You cannot make this safe, so no real point in trying.  You are handing out the raw pointer through the ReadOnlySpan, you don't know when the client code stopped using it.  Keeping the Memory field private and doing a dispose check in GetSpan() is advisable.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, that makes sense now that you mention it. I will document the potential for UAF and include a warning not to allow the `Slice<T>` lifetime to exceed that of the class instance that spawned it. Do you have a general preference on option 1 vs. option 2?

Comment: I have zero preference for the disposable pattern.  The *sealed* keyword is always better.  Do keep in mind that nobody knows what "UAF" means.

Comment: @HansPassant Fair. The intended userbase for this application is information security professionals, who do know what UAF means :)